# SSLException - Axis Connection shutdown on large request

Tags: java, ssl, axis

Since this week, I'm unable to get large responses from an Axis 1.4 Web service. My Web Service Client use to work well before this week. But now, when I fire a large request by using the stub, it ends with a "Connection has been shutdown [...] Connection reset by peer : socket write error".

Then I started to send smaller requests with the same stub method and I works fine... I tried to add a timeout to my stub "stub.setTimeout(10000)" but it didn't work. I've also set a timeout when I create SSL certificat like:

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
```

Did not work too...

Here is the first part of the complete error stacktrace...

```
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown:    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket    write error
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at ca.gc.shc.ws.SpineSoapBindingStub.interpolate(SpineSoapBindingStub.java:582)
at    ca.ogsl.ocean.clientsBridge.SpineClientAdaptor.interpolateAll(SpineClientAdaptor.java:220)
at ca.ogsl.ocean.clientsBridge.SpineRunnable.run(SpineRunnable.java:30)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ByteArray.writeTo(ByteArray.java:375)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:265)
at org.apache.axis.Message.writeTo(Message.java:539)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:511)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
... 18 more

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
```

Does someone have a clue or knows how can I solve that problem?

Oh... I'm using:
Eclipse - Tomcat 6 - Java 6 - Axis 1.4

Thank you very much for taking time to answer!!!